# SPARQL Apache Jena - HTTPException 404

Tags: sparql, jena, wikidata, httpexception, federated-queries

I have a problem with a `Federated Query`. It is used only as an **example** for my project.

I retrieve all Wikimedia Categories via DBpedia SPARQL Endpoint in Wikidata, but thats **not** the problem as the query below works in Wikidata.

But when I want to run it on Apache Jena Query, it throws an `HttpException 404`. **Why?**

Query:

```
prefix bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
prefix dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
prefix dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
SELECT ?objectLabel WHERE {
SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
       ?subject dct:subject dbc:Countries_in_Asia ; owl:sameAs ?object
       FILTER (STRSTARTS(STR(?object), "http://www.wikidata.org")) 
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

Java Code:

```
public static ResultSet executeQuery(String queryString, String service) {
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    QueryEngineHTTP queryEngine = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(service, query);
    ResultSet resultSet = queryEngine.execSelect();
    return resultSet;
}
```

Service = SPARQL Endpoint Service which I use `https://query.wikidata.org/sparql`

Exception Trace in Apache Jena:

```
HttpException: 404
at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:325)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:282)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:342)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:334)
```

Comment: Seriously, without seeing the Java code that does the querying, how can we help you?

Comment: How do you run the query in Jena?

Comment: Added Java code.

Comment: Works for me with your code, I tried with Apache Jena 3.3.0 - note, you're missing the `owl:` prefix declaration and the program should return with an exception. Thus, you're not showing the whole code or a different query.

Comment: Yes it works now for me. Apparently JUnit has huge problems with the coding from ISO-8859 to UTF-8. It has worked also before I updated from Apache Jena 3.2.0 to 3.4.0

Answer (score 2):

404 is returned by the remote server. wikibase:label is not a real SPARQL endpoint. You can not use it in a SERVICE clause if this is being executed locally with remote calls via SERVICE.

Comment: A right, the "magic" label service. I'm wondering how any federated query engine could ever execute this SPARQ? The standard semantics is bottom-up, right? Thus, data from both SERVICE clauses would be retrieved and joined locally. Even smarter engines couldn't do anything like push-through I guess because there is no variable overlap.

Comment: On the other hand, indeed it works if you use Wikidata as the remote endpoint in Jena.

Comment: Okay i removed the SERVICE clause, but it still remains a HttpException 404... Query still works in the Wikidata SPARQL Endpoint.

Comment: For me it works even with the SERVICE clause: `rsparql --service=https://query.wikidata.org/sparql --query /tmp/query.txt` where `query.txt` contains your original query.

Comment: And it works also with your code, I tried with Apache Jena 3.3.0 - note, you're missing the `owl:` prefix declaration and the code should return with an exception, thus, you're not showing the whole code or a different query.

Comment: 404 might be returned because of Wikidata endpoint was down. Or maybe the DBpedia endpoint, I don't know how Wikidata (resp. the Blazegraph backend) handles unaccessible SERVICE URLs.